# Delete untouched partition files on S3 bucket from unload

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift, amazon-athena

I have an `UNLOAD` statement that runs every day and sends data from a database to an S3 bucket. This data is `partitioned by` customer id and it works fine, but there's something I've just found out. If a customer gets deleted for example, the unload statement won't touch that partition as the source query has no data for that one and the S3 files won't be touched ever again.

I'm trying to control this directly from the unload instead of using external items, such bucket policies and so, is there another way of telling it to drop whatever is not on the source query? currently the unload options are:

`PARTITION BY (customerId) CLEANPATH PARALLEL OFF`

Comment: Do you run the `UNLOAD`  to fetch all the data from the table or just pull the latest updated records

Comment: It is more like a snapshot. Let's say I had yesterday 1 record for it, and tomorrow we don't. As I'm taking advantage of the partitioning, I want it to update the partitions with the new changes, hence the use of CLEANPATH, and get rid of the partitions that are not having any data on the new source.

Comment: From what I understand the `CLEANPATH` option would not work in this case as you are also using a `PARTITION BY` clause

> If you include the PARTITION BY clause, existing files are removed only from the partition folders to receive new files generated by the UNLOAD operation.

Comment: So in my case that CLEANPATH is a bit useless right? What can I do to mimic that logic? Still partitioning by customer Id but deleting any files that no longer have a customer id on the source?